# msdeploy contentPathLib provider replaces wwwroot by approot

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core-mvc, webdeploy, asp.net-core

I am trying to remotely deploy a vNext webapp to iis 7.5 using webdeploy 3.6 and msbuild with the contentPathLib provider as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/web-deploy-3-6-beta-released/).

Here is the msbuild task I use (the source "wwwroot" and "approot" folders are stored in the $(PackageDir), other variables names are selfspeaking)

> <Exec Command=""$(MSDeployExe)" -allowUntrusted -verbose -verb:sync -source:contentPathLib="$(PackageDir)wwwroot" -dest:contentPathLib=$(SiteName)/$(ApplicationName),computerName=$(ServerName)/msdeploy.axd?Site=$(SiteName),userName=$(WebDeployUserName),password=$(WebDeployPassword),authtype=basic -enableLink:contentLibExtension" />

The webapp configured in SiteName maps to an empty wwwroot folder.

After msbuild execution, the "wwwroot" folder of the application on the distant server has been renamed to "approot", instead of filling the "wwwroot" and creating a new "approot" folder.

The documentation is still quite poor on the subject (2016-01-14). Has anyone been able to perform a successful webdeploy of a vNext webapp?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this, I think. The trick seems to be to not define source and dest as contentPathLib, but as iisApp, then enable contentLinkExtension. I'm guessing most of the examples floating around out there involve deploying to IIS on the same server. So your task would be like so:

> <Exec Command=""$(MSDeployExe)" -allowUntrusted -verbose -verb:sync -source:iisApp="$(PackageDir)wwwroot" -dest:iisApp=$(SiteName)/$(ApplicationName),computerName=$(ServerName)/msdeploy.axd?Site=$(SiteName),userName=$(WebDeployUserName),password=$(WebDeployPassword),authtype=basic -enableLink:contentLibExtension" />

Full disclosure - I tried this on a Site, not an application within a site.